# conditionnaly change the status message?

Tags: 7, status-messages

I have a form that contain muliple lines...
every line represent an entity entry, and when submitting the form I get a very long status message :

```
- the entity 'ENTITY_NAME' has been saved.
- the entity 'ENTITY_NAME_2' has been saved. 
...
...
...
```

I want to change these messages to a single one, for example : "your changes have been saved"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are these entities? If they are custom entities you can take out the status message or specify a condition.

Comment: yes it's a custom entity created with ECK module, and every line in the form is a record to this entity!